# Timeout in Dropdown selectindex changed event

Tags: asp.net

I have built one web application and in that i had bound drop down with 10K records and when i will change index then i will get page timeout error!!

can anyone suggest me the cause of this problem?

Comment: Could be any number of things.  Please post the relevant code and more information (i.e., are you using a data source, etc).

Comment: if you load 10K records in a drop down list, not only you will have a huge page size, but the UI will be poorly usable (imagine your users having to scroll in these 10K records). Also, loading 10K records from a DB in a single query looks like weird. Specify your requirments, but in general, you will have to think about building a "selector" (JS based, postback based, etc.) that will help the user to find a value (keyword search, paged search, alphabetical search, etc)

Comment: Why do you bind a DropDownList to 10.000 Items?? Can't you group these items in any way? Then you could use [Cascading Dropdowns](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx), the user will thank you. As an alternative you could implement a prefilter for your items or use a paged GridView instead.

Comment: I have suggested to my client but he want this requirement as i have posted in question , all you guys are correct and i was also thinking same but it's requirement so can anyone give any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if you would not have the time out issue it would have been impossible for the users select the item they were looking for on a drop down list with 10k records!
Perhaps you should use another kind of control to show such a big resulset (Paged repeater/grid view) or anything that can be paged

Comment: I have suggested to my client but he want this requirement as i have posted in question , all you guys are correct and i was also thinking same but it's requirement so can you give any solution?

Comment: what you can do at this point is to use kind of "Jquery AutocComplete " drop down list so that you will filter the resulset againt what you are typing gain a bit on performance.
Show this at your client
http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

Comment: Finally i resolved this issue my own way 
Now dropdown will bind everytimes when postback occure (not from viewstate) and it will work without an error, thanks for all to give your opinion.